Using proxsuite within CVXPY
I have just installed "proxsuite" package for optimization purposes. In the main page of the package, it is stated that this is already incorporated in CVXPY. However, I am not able to call this algorithm. It has to be noted that the code is working with other algorithms such as GLPK.
Does anyone knows how to proceed?
Below the code:
import proxsuite
self.prob.solve(verbose = True, solver = 'PROXSUITE')
import proxsuite
self.prob.solve(verbose = True, solver = 'proxsuite')
(prob being the objective function)

proxsuite isn't just a solver you can call. The list of solvers available from CVXPY is in the table here https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/solvers/index.html#choosing-a-solver You probably want "PROXQP"
